# How to create release notes in bitbucket?

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control, bitbucket, release-notes

We are using Bitbucket as a remote server for version control system. Project is developed in Java using Eclipse IDE (Luna version). We are using integrated Git feature for managing source code versions with Bitbucket server. So, Is there any way we can create release notes from the comments/messages provided while committing the source code from Eclipse in Bitbucket?

Comment: In bitbucket server, it seems onlt jira issues can be created by commit message (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-smart-commits-in-bitbucket-server-802599018.html). For release notes, you can refer this plugin (https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/se.bjurr.changelog.git-changelog-for-bitbucket/server/overview).

Answer (score 5):

As of now, Bitbucket has no "native" way of creating release notes as the ones you could expect to find in, say, GitHub.

The only way I found to create a release notes when working in Bitbucket requires also JIRA, which is the project management tool from the same company (Atlassian).

In short, you would use the release tag in JIRA and all the tickets linked to it to generate the Release Notes (in JIRA itself). Once you have this, you can put the contents wherever you like except, of course, Bitbucket.

This is the official page for this process on Atlassian's website: [Create release notes](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/create-release-notes/)